# PineScript formulation of condition?

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, pine-script, conditional-formatting

Say I have 3 conditions, and I want to perform some action if 2 of these conditions are fulfilled. With a few number of combinations, like 3, the solution could be something like:

```
c1=...
c2=...
c3=...

if (c1==true and c2==true) then
elseif (c1==true and c3==true) then
elseif (c2==true and c3==true) then
```

**This is not very practical with, say, 100 conditions of which 90 should be fulfilled.
Is there a more compact way to implement this in PineScript?**

Comment: I don't know Pine Script, but from a quick look, it seems like most procedural languages. It depends on what your conditions are to determine how you should write this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you represent the boolean `true/false` of your condition as `1/0` ints, you could count them to see how many are true.

The shortest way I can think of, is putting them in an array, and calculate the sum of that array.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script")

var int c0 = 1
var int c1 = 0
var int c2 = 1
var int c3 = 1
var int c4 = 1
var int c5 = 0
var int c6 = 0
var int c7 = 1
var int c8 = 1
var int c9 = 1

var int[] a = array.from(c0,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9)

mySum = array.sum(a)

plot(mySum)
```